# JBOSS EAP 6.2 server crash due to out of memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, hornetq, jboss-eap-6

Facing the below issue in production environment but not reproducible in QA environment. Please help to resolve this issue.

We have a java application deployed in Jboss EAP 6.2 cluster setup using domain controller and using HornetQ as messaging system which has 4 queues and one topic and using MDB and MDP listeners for the queues and topic, application works fine with good server health for a week but after a week server crashes with out of memory error. I took the heap dump and analysed it with MAT and the finding is many instances of `ClientSessionFactoryImpl` (around 1,73,329 instances occupying 707MB of heap memory) is created and it is not getting garbage collected.

```
Problem Suspect 1

1,73,329 instances of "org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl", loaded by "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0x760004438" occupy 741,790,528 (83.13%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.HashMap$Entry[]", loaded by "<system class loader>"

Keywords
org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0x760004438
org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl
java.util.HashMap$Entry[]

OS: RHEL 6.8

server: Jboss EAP 6.2

java: JDK 1.6_24
```

[MAT Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCbxE.jpg)

Comment: There's not much to see here that we can help with, at least as far as I see. I would do a deep dive in your code and see if everything that needs closing is effectively closed.

Comment: we are using spring MDP and using org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer class for listening to topic, i believe spring will take care of the connection and in code i have only onMessage() method as part of the listener